# Capturing HID Descriptor stream from Game Controller.via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hid

I'm trying to capture HID Descriptors from a Sony PS4 Controller via Bluetooth. I've managed to establish a connection using the code below.

```
void findController() {
    int[] deviceIds = mInputManager.getInputDeviceIds();
    for (int deviceId : deviceIds) {
        InputDevice dev = mInputManager.getInputDevice(deviceId);
        int sources = dev.getSources();
        if (((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) ||
                ((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK) == InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK)) {
            // Device is a gamepad or joystick
            listStr = "Controller Found: \r\n";
            listTxt.setText(listStr);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm then using a listener to look for a key press or motion event but I've now been informed that I need to look for a data stream from the controller which contains different descriptors. The data is sent in binary data packets and needs to be converted to string data. I've been on Google most of today and although there is plenty of information about HID Descriptors I'm still not clear on how I collect the data.
If anyone has done something along these lines and can help to point me in the right direction or provide any useful links to help me resolve this, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to capture HID Descriptors...

Make sure you want to collect the `HID Descriptors` or the `HID data event`.
The HID over Bluetooth(BR/EDR or HOGP) works like below:
1) HID host use SDP to detect HID device's descriptors, i.e. to find out what the HID device is(e.g. a mouse, a keyboard) and parse the descriptors to find out which key represents which event. This procedure mainly occur when host and device's first connection.
2)HID host will register this device to local system.
3)Once HID host and HID device connected, HID host will parse the HID data stream or say event sent from HID device then mirror the event to system event e.g. click eject them to system.

So, in case you want to find out the descriptors, you might as well to unpair the device, then sniffer the log(for Android the btsnoop.log should be work) to find out the descriptor at the beginning of two device's connection.

Comment: Thank you Guo, that sounds like a solution. Do you have any sample code. As Stackoverflow offers a bounty option and this is important I would be happy to pay you for your time, let me know.

Comment: well thanks for you generous anyway :-)  what kind of "sample code" you want? so you just want the descriptors right?

Comment: Yes, any code that covers the three points you have listed. I've managed to use the Bluetooth classes to identify devices but after that I was using listeners which was wrong. If you can provide code to detect descriptors and register device then parse the data, that would help enormously. The offer was genuine as we have a budget so if it takes you any time then I would be happy to pay you for it. if you could load the code as addition to your answer that would be best.

Comment: Thanks, can you email me guoxingmin@outlook.com to make the request more clear; I would like to understand the tech background(e.g. hardware/software/stack  vendor and use case), I would not disclosure the information, thanks.